# Spam accounts being created via Facebook login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, devise

I've got a Rails App that uses Facebook for user accounts, and as of this evening, someone in Vietname has decided to (for whatever reason) use a bot to create fake accounts on my site using fake Facebook accounts. I'm getting about 2 new fake accounts / minute.

I've temporarily disabled registration, but I don't want to leave it that way, so I'm not sure what to do.

A couple things to note:
All the accounts use @yahoo.com or @ymail.com addresses
A lot of the accounts are registered by the same IP, but not all of them. It seems like he switches up the IP every 15 minutes or so.

I'm really at a loss, and I want to go to bed, but I can't until I find a solution to this. Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a capcha in registration form. If you already have a capcha in it then change the capcha generation mechanics. Also I think that your oponent made a script which is automaticly adds new user accounts to you web page, so as a temporary desicion you can change the url of registration handler.

Comment: I have a Captcha for my manual registration but not for the Facebook one. I guess that's probably the simplest solution at this point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use some techniques like limiting access to the application using something like a smart algo to block the IP it is requesting numerous account or limiting the account creation no more than a user from an IP.

And as specified if you know the pattern you can filter the request based on the pattern and deny any access.